# Fetched data from database between two range?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am try to get the leave report of users where I want to fetched data between two ranges and also if the leaves date lies between selected range.
e.g
Here is my db
[image]
Suppose I have selected range from 2017-06-13 to 2017-06-17 then second row should be selected and suppose I have selected range from 2017-06-21 to 2017-06-25 then also it should be selected I have tried below two different queries to get the same result

(a)

```
(SELECT u.user_id, u.user_image, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name, CONCAT(u.user_first_name, ' ', u.user_last_name) AS user_name, 
        u.user_email, p.driver_number, l.status, DATE_FORMAT(l.from_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as from_date, DATE_FORMAT(l.to_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as to_date 
        FROM (`bat_usermst` u) 
        JOIN `bat_leavemst` l ON `u`.`user_id` = `l`.`user_id` 
        JOIN `bat_profilemst` p ON `u`.`user_id` = `p`.`user_id` 
        WHERE `l`.`from_date` >= '" . $start . "' AND `l`.`from_date` <= '" . $end . "' AND 
        `l`.`status` = '1' AND `u`.`user_type` = 5 AND `u`.`user_status` = '1' AND `u`.`is_deleted` = '0' 
        ORDER BY `user_name`)

        UNION

        (SELECT u.user_id, u.user_image, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name, CONCAT(u.user_first_name, ' ', u.user_last_name) AS user_name, 
        u.user_email, p.driver_number, l.status, DATE_FORMAT(l.from_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as from_date, DATE_FORMAT(l.to_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as to_date 
        FROM (`bat_usermst` u) 
        JOIN `bat_leavemst` l ON `u`.`user_id` = `l`.`user_id` 
        JOIN `bat_profilemst` p ON `u`.`user_id` = `p`.`user_id` 
        WHERE `l`.`to_date` >= '" . $start . "' AND `l`.`to_date` <= '" . $end . "' AND 
        `l`.`status` = '1' AND `u`.`user_type` = 5 AND `u`.`user_status` = '1' AND `u`.`is_deleted` = '0' 
        ORDER BY `user_name`)
        ";
```

(b)

```
$this->db->select("u.user_id, u.user_image, u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name, CONCAT(u.user_first_name,' ', u.user_last_name) AS user_name,u.user_email, p.driver_number,l.status,
        DATE_FORMAT(l.from_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as from_date,
        DATE_FORMAT(l.to_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as to_date", FALSE);

        $this->db->from('usermst u');
        $this->db->join('bat_leavemst l', 'u.user_id = l.user_id');
        $this->db->join('profilemst p', 'u.user_id = p.user_id');
        $this->db->where('l.from_date >=', "$start");
        $this->db->where('l.to_date <=', "$end");
        $this->db->where('l.status', '1');
        $this->db->where(array('u.user_type' => DRIVER, 'u.user_status' => '1', 'u.is_deleted' => '0'));

        $this->db->order_by('user_name');
        $result = $this->db->get();
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and clarify your question by (a) showing sample query terms and the rows you want to fetch and (b) replacing the image with a text-based table, so we can read it. It might be your English, but I have no idea what you want your query to do.

Comment: why you did union? you can do that with simple `OR` condition.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your union query there is just one difference in where part of the query. 
Generally whenever you have complex `where` condition you can specify those conditions in as simple you write in MySQL.Below code should give the desired result.

```
$where = "((`l`.`from_date` >= '" . $start . "' AND `l`.`from_date` <= '" . $end . "') ".
         "OR (`l`.`to_date` >= '" . $start . "' AND `l`.`to_date` <= '" . $end . "')) ".
          "AND `l`.`status` = '1' AND `u`.`user_type` = 5 AND `u`.`user_status` = '1' AND `u`.`is_deleted` = '0'";
        $this->db->from('usermst u');
        $this->db->join('bat_leavemst l', 'u.user_id = l.user_id');
        $this->db->join('profilemst p', 'u.user_id = p.user_id');
        $this->db->where($where,NULL,FALSE);
        $this->db->order_by('user_name');
        $result = $this->db->get();
```